# Nested query in a view is giving me CHECK OPTION on non-updatable view

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE VIEW Res_borrow
AS
SELECT * 
FROM borrowing
WHERE mem_id IN (
    SELECT mpd.mem_id
    FROM (
        SELECT mem_id, COUNT(*) AS no_curr_bks
        FROM borrowing
        WHERE borrowing.ret_date IS NULL
        GROUP BY borrowing.mem_id
    )Y
    RIGHT JOIN mpd ON y.mem_id = mpd.mem_id
    WHERE y.no_curr_bks < mpd.nob OR y.no_curr_bks IS NULL
)
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

I tried to create such a view but i am getting error

Here is the schema of db

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBER
(
    mem_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    CHECK(CHAR_LENGTH(pass)>7),
    ph_no CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CHECK(gender='Female' OR gender='Male'),
    address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    age INT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    pkg_id INT DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (pkg_id) REFERENCES packages(pkg_id)
)

create table mpd --Member Package Details
(
    mem_id int primary key foreign key references member(mem_id),
    nob int not null default 2,
    dur int not null default 14
)

create table borrowing
(
    bor_id int primary key,
    mem_id int foreign key references member(mem_id) not null,
    book_id int foreign key references book(book_id),
    iss_date date not null,
    ret_date date
)
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, include the full and exact error message.  *(Also, try using more consistent indentation, etc, to make your query actually readable.)*

Comment: If you fix all the errors (~15) in your codes then the final error message will be `CHECK OPTION on non-updatable view`. This is absolutely infixable - remove only.